# Vuex and nested object in computed property causes reactivity problem

Tags: javascript, c, vue.js, vuex

I use a vuex store to handle a session and loading default sessions for different pages `onCreated` hook. Data is changing and most of the time it works fine but now I noticed even though I change the data, the setter / mutation is not called.

session.js (mixin to load default session from main component)

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      defaultSession: {}
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.$store.dispatch('session/update', { data: this.defaultSession })
  },
  computed: {
    sessionData: {
      get () {
        console.log('GETTER')
        return this.$store.getters['session/sessionData']
      },
      set (session) {
        console.log('SETTER')
        this.$store.dispatch('session/update', { data: session })
      }
    }

  }
}
```

store

```
export default {
  namespaced: true,

  state: {
    session: {},
  },

  getters: {
    session (state) {
      return state.session
    },
    sessionData (state) {
      return state.session.data
    },
  },

  mutations: {
    UPDATE (state, session) {
      state.session = session
      console.log('[Session] Updated')
    }
  },

  actions: {
    update: ({ commit }, data) => {
      commit('UPDATE', data)
    }
}
```

defaultSession example (in component)

```
        defaultSession: {
          name: '',
          viewId: '',
          defaultImage: null,
          dataTable: [{
            title: '',
            data: [],
            selected: [],
          }],
          imageTableData: [],
          selectedIcons: []
        },
```

So in my component I access `<input v-model="sessionData.name"/>` for instance, but neither the setter, nor the mutation is called. (The object is quite nested, because I also store table data inside.)

UPDATE (possible workaround):

```
watch: {
  sessionData: {
    deep: true,
    handler() {
       //commit changes here
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: since your `defaultSession` is quite big, for reactivity in depth try using `this.$set(state.someObject, 'b', 2)`, see details here https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Comment: I don't understand how I could achieve that, the v-model is already using `this.$set` and my computed setter is not even being called

Comment: UPDATE: added workaround to my question, but I think that is not the way it should be done